# I am getting error as TLS handshaking on hyperledger fabric peers and orderers

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, amazon-elb

I have setup hyperledger fabric 2.2 on EKS(elastic k8s). Now I want to use CAs, peers and orderers outside the k8s cluster so after researched I found aws NLB is support grpc protocol.
So I have  exposed peers and orderers as AWS NLB s but after NLB active the I am getting TLS handshaking error.
[image]

My NLB service.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: orderer0-nbl-service
  labels: {
    component: orderer0,
    type: orderer
  }
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
spec:
 selector:
    component: orderer0
    type: orderer
 ports:
   - name: endpoint
     port: 7050
     targetPort: 7050
 type: LoadBalancer
```

Please help me to find issue with it. I am not expert in AWS networking. I think some tls mismatching with AWS NLB and orderer and peers TLS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have setup Hyperledger Fabric 2.2.1 in Kubernetes cluster having One Orderer organization, One Working Organization and CA with TLS enable, I was able to connect using CLI container and perform different operations but was facing the same issue of TLS handshake error while from Node SDK calling the chaincode methods, while debugging  I have found that there were two problems, one I was referring wrong TLS certification file and other while connecting gateway I have disabled the discover as follow it worked for me, it might help you to resolve the issue.

```
// Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
    const gateway = new Gateway();
            await gateway.connect(ccp, {
        identity: userName, wallet: wallet, discovery: { enabled: false, asLocalhost: false }
    });
```

Here is [connection profile file](https://github.com/moolkothari/HLF-Connection-Profile/blob/main/connection-profile.yaml)